# Matching a recursive/multidimensional array against another array

Tags: php

I have the following array (called `$example_array` below):

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=> string(4) "123"
  ["name"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["first"]=> string(3) "pete"
        ["last"]=> string(3) "foo"
      }
  ["address"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["shipping"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["zip"]=> string(4) "1234"
              ["country"]=> string(4) "USA"
            }
      }
}
```

I would like a function that I can run against arrays like this and look for a match. Here are the searches that I would like to be able to perform:

```
// These should return true:
search( $example_array, array( 'id' => '123' ) );
search( $example_array, array( 'name' => array( 'first' => 'pete' ) );
search( $example_array, array( 'address' => array( 'shipping' => array( 'country' => 'USA' ) ) );

// These don't have to return true:
search( $example_array, array( 'first' => 'pete' ) );
search( $example_array, array( 'country' => 'USA' ) );
```

Is there a PHP internal function that I can use or will I have to code something myself?

Comment: Are those three arrays that should be matched in array or separately? What is logic of matching? Should item be matched if one of those is in array that should be searched or all of them should be matched?

Comment: Separately, each is an example of a search that can be performed against the example array.

Comment: looks like a database job

Comment: The data is coming from an API...

Comment: @LouisBataillard: can the API return XML? It would be much easier that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function search($array, $b) {
    $ok = true;
    foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($array[$key])) { $ok = false; break; }
        if (!is_array($value))
            $ok = ($array[$key] == $value);
        else 
            $ok = search($array[$key], $value);
        if ($ok === false) break;
    }
    return $ok;
}
```

Here's the [test script](http://pastebin.com/rkh7mC9s).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this function helps:

```
public function matchArray(&$arrayToSearch, $valueToMatch = array()){
    if(!is_array($valueToMatch))
        $valueToMatch = array($valueToMatch);

    $exists = false;
    $indexToMatch = array_keys($valueToMatch);

    foreach($indexToMatch as $ind){
        if(array_key_exists($ind, $arrayToSearch)){
            $valToMatch = $valueToMatch[$ind];
            $value = $arrayToSearch[$ind];
            $valType = gettype($value);
            $valToMatch = $valueToMatch[$ind];
            if($valType == gettype($valToMatch) || is_numeric($valToMatch)){
                if($valType == 'array'){
                    $exists = $this->matchArray($value, $valToMatch);
                } else if(($valType == 'string' || is_numeric($valToMatch)) && $valToMatch == $value) {
                    $exists = true;
                } else {
                    $exists = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $exists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin to do what you want, iirc.

Here's an (untested) version with `array_walk`:

```
function search($data,$match) {
   return  array_walk($match, function($v,$k) use ($data) {
      if (isset($data[$k])){
         if (is_array($v)) return search($data[$k],$v);
         return ($v == $data[$k]);
      });
      return false;
 }
```

It's somewhat concise (one could do better with `?:`), but perhaps not very readable. Lambdas are a great addition to php!

Here's another possible solution, but seemingly inneficient (you should benchmark to make sure):

```
 function search($d,$m) {
    return is_empty(array_diff_assoc(array_intersect_assoc($d,$m), $m));
 }
```

Maybe it won't work if the builtin used are not recursives.